# Eclipse Android SDK Manager - some packages are missing

Tags: android, eclipse

I am beginner in Android programming. Can anybody tell me, how can I add more packages to Android SDK Manager? As you can see in the picture below, I have a list which contains API 19, API 17, API 16, API 10, Tools and Extras, but no other APIs. How can I add for example API 12?

Thanks for helping.

[image: Android SK Manager]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have figured out the answer on my own. In Android SDK Manager I have opened the Tools folder and there I have updated the Android SDK Tools, because the last time I did this was approximately a year ago. Now it works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Try a command line approach . use cmd or terminal to get command window . type 'android' st prompt which launch an executable from /sdkroot/tools.

The ui will let you install new API version like 12.

Answer (score 0):

Untick the "Installed" check box at the bottom of the window.